# Why in a template we can use a dependent name without being already declared if not instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, dependent-name

I have written this code to understand `template` name lookup:

```
//void bar(int);

template <typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
    bar(x);
}

void bar(int x)
{
    std::cout << "bar(int)\n";
}

template <int>
void foo(int i)
{
    bar(i);
}



int main()
{

    foo<int>(4);


    std::cout << "\ndone!\n";
}
```

I've commented out the declaration of function `bar(int)` intentionally. This function `bar(int)` is used as a `dependent name` in the template function `foo`. So it is bound upon instantiation.

- I've defined `bar` right after `foo` and before a specialization of `foo<int>` so that this latter can see `bar(int)`.

But when I compile the code I get this error:

`‘bar’ was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]|`. And if I un-comment the declaration of `bar(int)` it works fine?!

- If I must declare a name before using it in a template as a dependent-name then why C++ allows that if not instantiated. (the code works if I don't "use" templated function `foo`)?

  ```
    template <typename U>
    void do_it(U u)
    {
        print(u); // not bound until instantiation
    }
  ```

So what is the idea behind allowing calling `print(u)` in `do_it` which was not already declared and will fail upon instantiation?

Comment: `print(u)` is not actually allowed. It's just that you don't necessarily get an error message.

Comment: @idclev463035818: Because it uses the template parameter type.

Comment: oh right, my bad.

Comment: Hmm, I think I see where part of your confusion lies. You don't have a specialization of `foo` at all. You're declaring a completely different entity. You need `template<> void foo<int>(int i);` The code is fine then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program, this definition:

```
template <int>     // not a specialization, just a different
void foo(int i)    // template with a non-type template parameter
{
    bar(i);
}
```

does not actually define a specialization of the `foo` primary template. So when you make this call:

```
Foo<int>(4);
```

you end up calling the primary template. Lookup for the name `bar` doesn't find that name, and you get an error.

If instead, you actually write a specialization of `foo` for `int` like this:

```
template <>           // specialization of primary
void foo<int>(int i)  // template foo with int
{
    bar(i);
}
```

then the call `foo<int>(4);` is fine, because it calls the specialization, and lookup for `bar` at that point does find that name.

---

Now going back to your program (without the specialization), what happens if `foo` is never instantiated, because there's no call, for example? Well, the program is still wrong, but the compiler may not tell you about it. This is the behavior that you are describing with `print` and `do_it`, and this is formally known as *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the line numbers in that error output.

You’re instantiating the first template. The second template is not a specification of the first but a function template that requires an `int` template parameter that it doesn’t use.

Comment: Thank you! what you mean with error numbers in the output?

Comment: Warnings and errors typically have line numbers associated with them. `file.cpp:128` for example is the 128th line of `file.cpp`.